# Accordion content won't display

Tags: javascript, css, accordion

I'm making an informative website with a nav bar and accordion. When I load the webpage, the content inside the accordion won't display. I think there is an issue with the panel and display.Is there an issue with the nav bar and accordion styling.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Sunscreen</title>
<style>

header{
    background-color: #FFC288;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #ec9a3a;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 60px;
    font-size:38px;
    font-family:Barbieri Inline ;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:20;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #FFC288 ;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #ec9a3a;
    font-family:Barbieri;
    color:white;

  }
li {
    float: left;
  }
  
  li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  li a:hover {
    background-color:#FEA82F ;
  }

body{
    background-color: #51C3DE;
  }

  #container{
    position: absolute;
    height:360px;
    width: 360px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;

}

#schoice{
    position:absolute;
    height:450px;
    width:420px;
    right:160px;
    bottom:90px;
    background-color:#FFC288;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #ec9a3a;
    font-family:Barbieri;
    color:white;
}

h2{
    font-family:Barbieri Inline;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;

}


  .accordion {
    background-color: #FFC288;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-family:Barbieri Inline ;
    border: 2px solid #ec9a3a;
        color:white;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 18px;
      width: 50%;
      text-align: left;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 15px;
      transition: 0.4s;
    }
    
    .active, .accordion:hover {
        background-color:#FEA82F
    }
    
    .panel {
      padding: 0 18px;
      display: none;
      background-color: white;
      overflow: hidden;
      font-family:Barbieri Inline ;
      color:#FEA82F;
      width:50%;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
</script>
<header> Sun Protection</header>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
        <li><a href="responsiveshell.html"> Home </a></li>
        <li><a href="">Alcohol Safety</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Uber/Nighttime Navigation Tips</a></li>
      </ul>
<button class="accordion">Skin Cancer Statistics</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>The Skin Cancer Foundation states that melanoma is the second MOST COMMON type of cancer diagnosed in 15-19 year olds and the most common form of cancer affecting young adults between the ages of 25-29.</p>
  <p> Sustaining just 5 sunburns as a teenager can make an adult 80% more likely to develop melanoma during their lifetime.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Signs and Symptoms of Skin Cancer</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Sunburn Care</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Go to your local pharmacy or convenient store to purchase alloe. If you don't have any, you can create a paste made from water and baking soda and apply it to the burn area to relieve some of the pain and heat.</p>
  <p>Make sure to be drinking water and staying hydrated. The body tries to heal the burn by drawing moisture from other areas of the </p>
</div>
    <div id="container">
        <img src="sunscreen.png" height="360px" width="360px"></src>
        </div>

    <div id="schoice">

        <h2> What Type of Sunscreen is Right for Me?</h2>
       </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I've tried to adjust the css content but I'm not sure if that is where the problem lies.

```
header{
    background-color: #FFC288;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #ec9a3a;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 60px;
    font-size:38px;
    font-family:Barbieri Inline ;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:20;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #FFC288 ;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #ec9a3a;
    font-family:Barbieri;
    color:white;

  }
li {
    float: left;
  }
  
  li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  li a:hover {
    background-color:#FEA82F ;
  }

body{
    background-color: #51C3DE;
  }

  #container{
    position: absolute;
    height:360px;
    width: 360px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;

}

#schoice{
    position:absolute;
    height:450px;
    width:420px;
    right:160px;
    bottom:90px;
    background-color:#FFC288;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #ec9a3a;
    font-family:Barbieri;
    color:white;
}

h2{
    font-family:Barbieri Inline;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;

}


  .accordion {
    background-color: #FFC288;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-family:Barbieri Inline ;
    border: 2px solid #ec9a3a;
        color:white;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 18px;
      width: 50%;
      text-align: left;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 15px;
      transition: 0.4s;
    }
    
    .active, .accordion:hover {
        background-color:#FEA82F
    }
    
    .panel {
      padding: 0 18px;
      display: none;
      background-color: white;
      overflow: hidden;
      font-family:Barbieri Inline ;
      color:#FEA82F;
      width:50%;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome! Remove one of the blocks of CSS. That's a bunch of code and if it's not relevant - since we have no idea what you changed - it's too much for us to go through to help you.

Comment: Please be specific about what's not working. I copied your code to a snippet, broke out the CSS and JS from the HTML, and the panels expand when I click the accordion buttons. I don't know what problem you're describing.